# Listener doesnt work for dynamically added radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following listener:

```
   $('#datatable .Answer input:radio').on('change', function() {
        alert('Radio Button');

    });
```

And I add radio button dynamically to this table '#datatable' as follows:

```
   $(this).html('<input type="radio" class="Answer" name="correct"/>');
```

where this is the  td element in which radio button should be added.
Why doesn't the listener work on new elements?

Comment: *"Why doesn't the listener work on new elements?"* You can find an answer to that in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/): *"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the listener work on new elements?

Because you should subscribe to the change event like this:

```
$('#datatable .Answer').on('change', 'input:radio', function() {
    alert('Radio Button');

});
```

Notice how the `'input:radio'` selector is moved to the `.on()` function in order to subscribe to the event in a *lively* manner.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I knew it was a similar mistake to something I had done earlier.

Comment: I said thanks widout trying it seems it still doesn;t work :(

Comment: Now its working I had to move the .Answer also in the live part.